# Using ps2pdf correctly in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ghostscript

I have a script below and I am having problems. I have several folders with PostScript file in them I want to batch convert to PDFs. I have done very little scripting in linux before but I think this is close. It is not quite working how I want it though. Any suggesting? or notice a mistake I made? I want the files to stay in the same location after they have been converted. Currently this converts the files but they get all put together in one folder.

I call the script  like this: ./all.ps.to.pdf "/directory/to/process"

```
#!/bin/sh

STARTDIR=$1
if [ ! -d "$STARTDIR" ]; then
echo No starting directory $STARTDIR
exit 1
fi

find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print | sed -e 's/.ps$//' |
xargs -l -i  ps2pdf \{}.ps
```

Comment: Your `find` command should be all in one line. Or, if you want to distribute it over two lines, use ` \` as the line continuation sign (which must be the very last characters on the first line without any blanks following it!)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle - if "|" is the final token of the line, you don't need the line continuation character: "\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> notice a mistake I made?

Yessss, Sir.

Your `find` command should be all in one line. Or, if you want to spread it over two lines, use `\` as the line continuation sign (which must be the very last character on the first line without any blanks following it!).

That is...

- either use

  ```
  find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print | sed -e 's/.ps$//' | xargs -l -i  ps2pdf \{}.ps
  ```
- or use

  ```
  find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print | sed -e 's/.ps$//' | \
  xargs -l -i  ps2pdf \{}.ps
  ```
- or even use

  ```
  find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print \
    | sed -e 's/.ps$//'              \
    | xargs -l -i  ps2pdf \{}.ps
  ```

(whichever you think looks "nicer" to your Bash reading eyes...).

Answer (score 2):

Just give it the PDF output filename explicitly:

```
find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print | sed -e 's/.ps$//' | xargs -l -i  ps2pdf '{}.ps' '{}.pdf'
```

Comment: What version of `xargs` takes `{}` as a parameter?

Comment: Most Linux xargs; `-i` means use `{}` as the replaced string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps' -print |
while read filename
do
  ps2pdf ${filename} ${filename%.ps}.pdf
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i `find $STARTDIR -name '*.ps'` ; do ps2pdf $i $i.ps.pdf ; done
```